# Rails on Heroku: No route error only on Chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm building a clone for Tinder using Rails [here](https://tinderusth.herokuapp.com/). The app can run locally without any error. I'm using Rails 4.2.6
When I deploy the app on Heroku, the function like/dislike for the app doesn't work, but only on Chrome. In the logs file it says no route

 I tried to use Safari and it can run without any problem. 
 I have cleared the cache 
I took a look at Heroku [logs file](http://pastebin.com/yjqaMk85) and I found that the method for Chrome is GET while on Safari it's POST.

Here's the logs (I removed the time stamp) 
On chrome:

```
at=info method=GET path="/users/4/like_user" host=tinderusth.herokuapp.com request_id=25ad4d9f-f37c-4386-8192-0ba81e7431af fwd="42.112.242.134" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=41ms status=404 bytes=1829
Started GET "/users/4/like_user" for 42.112.242.134 at 2016-05-30 14:11:32 +0000
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/users/4/like_user")
```

On Safari:

```
at=info method=POST path="/users/9/like_user" host=tinderusth.herokuapp.com request_id=9b6951a4-9fc1-4d18-b43e-e0594bf82e6a fwd="42.112.242.134" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=68ms status=302 bytes=1026
User Load (2.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"Wz+R/8pl+/R7vlwex6fL1PWgVUQmdqHj3FwCjtu75GQMk7sQ6Q4gwbfUAILQElAFJA8DtmPSf3jh9LrQpTMYYQ==", "id"=>"9"}
app[web.1]: Started POST "/users/9/like_user" for 42.112.242.134 at 2016-05-30 14:12:04 +0000
app[web.1]:   User Load (4.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 9]]
```

My route.rb: (I use devise gem)

```
devise_for :users
 resources :posts
 resources :users do
  member do
   post :like_user, :superlike_user
  end
 end
 resources :profiles
 resources :matches do
  member do
   delete :unlike_user
  end
 end
root 'users#index'
```

Both rendered the same view:

```
<a class="users-button like-button" id="like_user_1" rel="nofollow" data-method="post" href="/users/1/like_user">
  <span title="Like this user" class="fa fa-thumbs-up hvr-bounce-in" aria-hidden="true">
  </span>
</a>
```

Thank you for your helps.

Comment: If the same link produces 2 different actions, take a look at that link. can you post a view that produces link/button ? open in it chrome dev tools, and in safari, does method you use produces different html in different browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Chrome doesn't interpret your `data-method: :post`.

Chrome : `Started GET`

Safari: `Started POST`

Try to do this with a `button_to` which enables you to bypass these limitations. (http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to)